# How do you place imageView on to of another imageView always in the same spot despite of the screen size or aspect ratio?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZOtS.png)I am trying to create an app where a circle moves on top of random place on an `ImageView`. I have a placeholder `TextView` on the map which is supposed to tell the circle where to go. The problem occurs when I build the app to my phone and test it. The circle nor the placeholder textView is nowhere near the place where I wanted them to be. and the circle is not even on top of the textView. So here is the question: How can I keep the placeholder in the same spot on the map in every aspect ratio and screen size AND how can I move the circle on top of the placeholder?

I have been searching for an answer for almost two days now and I am starting to feel a little frustrated.

Here is my java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Random random;

    ImageView theMap;
    ImageView pointerCircle;

    int randomNum;

    //PLACEHOLDERS
    TextView place1;
    TextView place2;
    TextView place3;
    TextView place4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        theMap = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.theMap);
        pointer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pointer);

        //DEFINING THE PLACEHOLDERS
        place1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place1);
        place2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place2);
        place3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place3);
        place4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place4);

        random = new Random();
    }

    public void findSpot(View view) {
        randomNum = random.nextInt(4) + 1;

        shuffle(randomNum);
    }

    public void shuffle(final int theNum) {
        switch (theNum) {
            case 1:
                pointer.setY(place1.getY());
                pointer.setX(place1.getX());
            case 2:
                pointer.setY(place2.getY());
                pointer.setX(place2.getX());
            case 3:
                pointer.setY(place3.getY());
                pointer.setX(place3.getX());
            case 4:
                pointer.setY(place4.getY());
                pointer.setX(place4.getX());
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
tools:context="com.example.aapotti.randomplaceonamap.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_border"
    android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
    android:onClick="findSpot"
    android:text="Find random spot!"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="493dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pointer"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="184dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="204dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/pointer" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/theMap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/normalmap">

    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/placeholder"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: use framelayout.

Comment: I have been trying to. How do you do it? I have tried just to put both of the images inside it and adjusted the margins of the top layer until it is in the correct spot but it doesn't seem to make any difference. When I change the screen size it still moves off the spot it should be on.

Comment: item added last in framelayout will be shown on top, not the first item in layout. It literally stacks the views.

Comment: Yes, but still when I put them inside a frame layout and change the device the placeholder is not on the same spot than it was in different screen size. So the frame layout has a width and height of wrap content, the map has both as match parent and the place holder has constant width and height of 15dp (because it really doesn't matter it is just there for the coordinates of the spot in the map underneath). When the screen size changes the map gets smaller or bigger and the placeholder appears in a different spot on the map than in previous screen size.

Comment: The FrameLayout itself is in ConstraintLayout and it is constainted to the middle of the screen.

Comment: update your question with relative code for frame layout.

Comment: It is now updated.

Comment: set layout widhth and height to 0dp and set constraint_width and height to wrap

Comment: So do you mean the frame layout width and height to 0dp? And what do you mean by constrait_width and height? Sorry it might be obvious.

Comment: constraint layout has this property that you need to set to wrap `app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"`

Comment: Ok I changed frame layouts width and height 0dp and constraint layouts constraintWidth and height to wrap but the placeholder TextView still moves from its place. I modified the XML above accordingly.

Comment: shouldn't your maps height and width be set to wrap_content?

Comment: Maby it should but when I change it the map jumps to the top of the screen and it doesn't change anything about the placeholder changing its place when switching to another screen size.

Comment: can you post screenshots for what you want and how your view looks currently.

Comment: remove all constraints inside frame layout as they won't work.

Comment: I'll add picture in 15 mins.

Comment: I dont see if you can see the picture. I hope so. So that is with a screen size with 1080x1920. The white square should be on brazil, which it was with screen size of 480x800.

Comment: try doing this, set your map image as background to constraint layout and use only imageview as pointer, remove all other layout and try. this should work.

Comment: How can I use the image as a background and keep the same aspect ratio which is 1:1?

Comment: It doesn't work ether I'm sorry.